# Adding a hyperlink button in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress based webpages (tsc.dk) where I have a theme that I'm customizing rather then building from scratch.

The problem I have now is that I can't figure out how I add button with a hyperlink to another page.

I have tried

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="Link" onclick="window.location.href='http://www.excampel.com'"/>
</form>
```

But it doesn't work in the php file.
The rest of the file looks likes this and I would just like to add a button with a hyperlink in the bottom

```
<?php 
global $heal_option;
$sort_section = $heal_option['heal_seciton_sorter']['Enabled'];

if ($sort_section): foreach ($sort_section as $key=>$value) {

switch($key) {

    case 'about': get_template_part( 'sections/about', 'about' );
    break;

    case 'team': get_template_part( 'sections/team', 'team' );
    break;

    case 'service': get_template_part( 'sections/service', 'service' );
    break;

    case 'testimonial': get_template_part( 'sections/testimonial', 'testimonial' );
    break;

    case 'gallery': get_template_part( 'sections/gallery', 'gallery' );    
    break;  

    case 'causes': get_template_part( 'sections/causes', 'causes' );    
    break; 

    case 'news': get_template_part( 'sections/news', 'news' );    
    break; 

    case 'event': get_template_part( 'sections/event', 'event' );    
    break; 

    case 'client': get_template_part( 'sections/client', 'client' );    
    break; 

    case 'contact': get_template_part( 'sections/contact', 'contact' );    
    break;   

    }

 }
 endif;
 ?>
```

Comment: Remove endif; and then try it, It Works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)